# Sequencing Thread Pool Outputs to Stream Data

Tags: c#, .net

There are a lot of resources about synchronizing Threads, ie, when and how to start them.
However, I would like to launch Threads, and retrieve output results, in an ordered fashion.

For example, if I have : 
Thread 1 Ouput : Data 1
Thread 2 Ouput : Data 2
Thread 3 Ouput : Data 3

I would start Threads sequentially (Thread 1, 2, 3), and I want to retrieve Data in an Ordered List (Data 1, 2, 3). As you know I have no guarantee that Thread 2 will finish and deliver its output before Thread 3. So I need some efficient way to reintroduce sequentiality and order as the threads are delivering their desired outputs.

**EDIT :** 
Very important precision (as noted by a commentator) : 
Thread Pool is going to run 24/7 and Data is NOT a fixed set but a Data Stream. 
Plus, I am bound to .Net 3.5 because of legacy issues.

Comment: Why bother with threading if you want the output to be sequential anyway?

Comment: Is it for one fixed set of data, or you plan to run the threads concurrently for some time (aka pipeline)?

Comment: @M.Babcock You can use threading to process items quickly, but still want the results in an ordered manner.  This is not an uncommon requirement.

Comment: @M.Babcock : Because I'm so bored in my life and My GF just dropped me and I have nothing else to do but ask dumb questions on SOF :-))))))  Let's just say I have my valuable technical reasons, exactly how Reed Copsey stated it :-)

Comment: @alexm : Very good question. I'll make an edit on it.

Answer (score 1):

A good option here is to use PLINQ.

It lets you write a query that creates your data, as follows:

```
var results = inputData.AsParallel().AsOrdered().Select(inputValue => ComputeOutputData(inputValue));
```

In this case, the call to [AsOrdered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642142.aspx) will allow the query to be run in parallel, but your results to come back in the original order appropriately.

Comment: One caveat you may want to mention is that PLINQ is only (fully) available in .NET 4. If you're using anything earlier you'll need to implement your own synchronization mechanisms.

Comment: @MikaJacobi You can still use PLINQ by installing the Reactive Extensions.  There is a full back-port of the entire TPL inside Rx: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609